# How to save multiple stocks data frame into different separate csv files?

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv, yahoo-finance

Sample code:

```
tickers = ["FB", "AMZN", "AAPL", "NFLX", "GOOG", "^GSPC",...]
multpl_stocks = web.get_data_yahoo(tickers,
start = "2013-01-01",
end = "2014-03-01"())
```

I would like to save all tickers at the same time into different csv files.

Of course, I know the following code which just save one of the data frames.

```
apple = web.get_data_yahoo("AAPL",
                        
                            start = "2009-01-01",
                            end = datetime.now())
```

But, I want to save them at the same time each one  into a csv file .

I do not want to do that one by one as it takes a lot time

I tried the following code ,but did not work

```
 apple, goog, fb  = web.get_data_yahoo("AAPL","GOOG", "FB"
                        
                            start = "2009-01-01",
                            end =  "2013-01-01))

apple, goog, fb.to_csv(r("c:\desktop\users\fb.csv, goog.csv, apple.csv"))
```

I want the result to be like this and be stored  in my pc:

fb.csv

goog.csv

apple.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web #I assume this is what you have
from datetime import datetime

tickers = ["FB", "AMZN", "AAPL", "NFLX", "GOOG"] #and everything else

for stock in tickers:
 stock_data = web.get_data_yahoo(stock, start = "2009-01-01", end = datetime.now())
 df = pd.DataFrame(stock_data)
 df.to_csv(stock + ".csv", index=False)
```

Comment: thanks. But, I don't know yet where each of the stocks is to be saved. And,  Have the stocks  to  be stored one by one? or for each one I must select a folder of my pc? I am confused yet.

Comment: it stores each stock with the name like `FB.csv`, and those files are stored in same folder as your python script. You can change that by specifying folder in `df.to_csv()` line.

Comment: If you want them to be stored in a specific folder, feel free to comment it here and i will edit my answer.

Comment: thanks. Yes . Would you explain what you want to tell me in more details ? one by one. And in a more friendly way which I have not to be input them as it takes a long time.

Comment: If you want those CSV files to be stored in a certain folder, you must specify the folder to the `to_csv`. Currently it stores the csv files in same folder where you execute your python script.